# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{\left(t\pi x^2\right)}}{\sinh^2{\left(\pi x\right)}} \; \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Evaluate $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{\left(t\pi x^2\right)}}{\sinh^2{\left(\pi x\right)}} \; \mathrm{d}x$$

I converted $\sinh{(x)}$ to exponential form and considered Imaginary part of the numerator:
$$4\Im{\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{2 \pi x}e^{t\pi x^2}}{{\left(e^{2 \pi x} -1\right)}^2} \; \mathrm{d}x\right)}$$
I think a semi circle contour in upper quadrants would work.  Residues are at $x=k \cdot i, k \in \mathbb{N}$ including $0i$.  Where I calculated the residues to be
$$-\frac{2t}{\pi} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ne^{-n^2 \pi i t}$$
I dont know what to do from here (closed form) or maybe my work is wrong?  Ideas or tips please.

Comment: Try integrating by parts, taking derivatives with respect to sine and integrating with respect to sinh

Comment: @Moko19 I just tried it and I'm stuck on $$\frac{1}{2 \pi}\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{\sin{(t \pi x^2)}}{e^{2 \pi x}-1}+ t \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x \cos{(t \pi x^2)}}{e^{2 \pi x}-1} \; \mathrm{d}x$$
I tried contour integration again with the new integral but get the same sum.  Is this what you meant?

Also integral is $$2t \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x  \coth{(\pi x)} \cos{(t \pi x^2)} \; \mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61605/tough-integral-involving-sinx2-and-sinh2-x?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Quanto How would I adjust $f(z)$?  I know this is wrong, but if I use $$f(z)=\frac{\cos\left(t \pi z^2\right)}{\sinh(2\pi z)\sinh^2(\pi z)}$$ or is this wrong?  Using this $f(z)$ I got $$I=\left(\frac{1}{2} + \cos{\left(\frac{\pi t}{4}\right)}+ \frac{\pi(2t^2-1)\cos{(\pi t)}+t\sin{(\pi t)}}{2\pi}\right)$$ where $t=\frac{b}{a}$ but this is wrong according to values of $t$ in Wolfram (only $t=1$ is right).

Comment: $a/b$ has to be rational numbers. This is connected to Gauss sums (Ramanujan). Contour integral won't work for more complex cases.

Comment: @User628759  Indeed. The integral is an easy generalization of techniques [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2717244). The answer involves Gauss sum, which in some cases, can be simplified non-trivially.

Comment: @pisco I remenber Ramanujan evaluates a lot of them, with values of form $P(\frac1 \pi)$, $P$ polynomial. I generalized some of them to arbitrary weights a year ago, so I decided not to post this again. : ) Your technique is also ingenious.